# php pass variable amount of soap params to soap client

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I have a php soap client that generates the xml envelope and request.  I need to pass in a variable amount of nodes to the request.  As I do not know how many arguments will be passed in it needs to be dynamic.

```
$output = $this->_client->UpdateRequest(
            new SoapParam($this->_memberId, "MemberID"),
            new SoapParam($this->_userId, "UserID"),
            new SoapParam(Functions::getRemoteIp(), "IPAddress"),
            new SoapParam($this->_macaddress, "HardwareID"),
            new SoapParam($data->applicationId, "ApplicationID"),
            new SoapParam($application,"Application"),
            new SoapParam($applicants,"Applicant") <----- THIS IS AN ARRAY
        );
```

I need it to look like this in the request:

```
<UpdateRequest>
   <MemberID>1</MemberID>
   etc etc...
   <Applicant>   <--------- REPEATING NODE
        .....
   </Applicant>
   <Applicant>
        .....
   </Applicant>
   <Applicant>
        .....
   </Applicant>
</UpdateRequest>
```

Any ideas?